# Кнопка нравится с использованием cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Есть код кнопки нравится. На данный момент один пользователь может нажимать на кнопку любое количество раз. Хотелось бы привязать как-то это все к cookie, чтобы пользователь мог нажать на кнопку нравится один раз. Также необходимо учесть, что на одной странице должно быть несколько статей с кнопкой нравится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ФАЙЛ like.php

```
<?php

    /** Данные для подключения к Базе Данных */
    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = 'test';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';

    /** Подключаемся в Базе Данных */
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. $host .';dbname='.$database.';charset=utf8', $user, $password);
    $pdo->exec("SET NAMES utf8");

    /** Получаем наш ID статьи из запроса */
    $id = intval($_POST['id']);
    $count = 0;
    $message = '';
    $error = true;

    /** Если нам передали ID то обновляем */
    if($id){
        /** Обновляем количество лайков в статье */

        $query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE article SET count_like = count_like+1  WHERE id = :id");
        $query->execute(array(':id'=>$id));

        /** Выбираем количество лайков в статье */
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count_like FROM article WHERE id = :id");
        $query->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
        $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $count = isset($result['count_like']) ? $result['count_like']  : 0;

        $error = false;
    }else{
        /** Если ID пуст - возвращаем ошибку */

        $error = true;
        $message = 'Статья не найдена';
    }


    /** Возвращаем ответ скрипту */

    // Формируем масив данных для отправки
    $out = array(
        'error' => $error,
        'message' => $message,
        'count' => $count,
    );

    // Устанавливаем заголовот ответа в формате json
    header('Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8');

    // Кодируем данные в формат json и отправляем
    echo json_encode($out);
    ?>
```

ФАЙЛ script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".like").bind("click", function() {
        var link = $(this);
        var id = link.data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/like.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: {id:id}, // Передаем ID нашей статьи
            dataType: "json", 
            success: function(result) {
                if (!result.error){ //если на сервере не произойло ошибки то обновляем количество лайков на странице
                    link.addClass('active'); // помечаем лайк как "понравившийся"
                    $('.counter',link).html(result.count);
                }else{
                    alert(result.message);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Мне кажется делать это в куках - плохая идея (куки ведь удалять можно). Подумайте как эту информацию хранить в бд

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц, меня интересует вопрос реализации именно в куках

Comment: [работа с куками](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".like").bind("click", function() {
    var link = $(this);
    var id = link.data('id');
    if ($.cookie('like') != 'true') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/like.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          id: id
        }, // Передаем ID нашей статьи
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
          if (!result.error) { //если на сервере не произойло ошибки то обновляем количество лайков на странице
            $.cookie('like', 'true');
            link.addClass('active'); // помечаем лайк как "понравившийся"
            $('.counter', link).html(result.count);
          } else {
            alert(result.message);
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("Вы уже ставили лайк");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="like">like</button>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что если у меня две кнопки нравится и более, к ним та же кука идет, нажимаю на одну, другие тоже больше не нажимаются

Comment: Ну значит как то разделить надо для каждой кнопки свои куки. Например после название кука добавляйте уникальный индификатор кнопки

Answer (score 0):

[jquery cookie](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0_%D1%81_cookie)

внутри  $(".like").bind("click", function() проверяйте есть ли кука, если нет, реагировать если есть то ничего не делать.

Но куки удаляются периодически, если хотите для пользователя хранить постоянно статус "лайкнуто", то лучше это как-то в БД хранить

Comment: да, я понимаю что нужно что-то подобное сделать, но я не могу разобраться как это прописать

Comment: @alexprosto Дак я вам скинул как куки записать а потом считать

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц Ну... я к сожалению настолько глуп, что мне этого недостаточно